# How to show Hijri and Gregorian dates together using react native

Tags: react-native, momentjs, gregorian-calendar, hijri, react-native-calendars

I'm trying to display both hijrj and gregorian dates. However it only shows gregorian.

This is the code.

Libraries

```
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
import moment from 'moment-hijri';
import HijriDate from 'hijri-date';
```

Hooks and other

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(moment().format('iYYYY-iM-iD'));
const [hijriDate, setHijriDate] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    const date = new HijriDate();
    const monthNames = [
      'Muharram',
      'Safar',
      'Rabi al-Awwal',
      'Rabi al-Thani',
      'Jumada al-Awwal',
      'Jumada al-Thani',
      'Rajab',
      'Shaaban',
      'Ramadan',
      'Shawwal',
      'Dhu al-Qidah',
      'Dhu al-Hijjah',
    ];
    const month = monthNames[date.getMonth() - 1];
    const formattedDate = `${date.getDate()} ${month}, ${date.getFullYear()}`;

    setHijriDate(formattedDate);
  }, []);
```

Custom header

```
 const renderHeader = (date) => {
    const gregorianDate = moment(date.dateString).format('MMMM, YYYY');
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Text style={{ color: COLORS.green, fontSize: 25 }}>{gregorianDate}</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: COLORS.green, fontSize: 25 }}>{hijriDate}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Calendar

```
<Calendar
            markingType="custom"
            // selectedDate={moment()}
            // markedDates={markedDates}
            onDayPress={onDayPress}
            style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginVertical: 10 }}
            theme={{
              calendarBackground: COLORS.white,
              textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
              selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#00adf5',
              selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
              todayTextColor: '#00adf5',
              dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
              textDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
              dotColor: '#00adf5',
              selectedDotColor: '#ffffff',
              arrowColor: 'orange',
              monthTextColor: 'white',
              indicatorColor: 'blue',
              textDayFontFamily: 'monospace',
              textMonthFontFamily: 'monospace',
              textDayHeaderFontFamily: 'monospace',
              textDayFontSize: 16,
              textMonthFontSize: 16,
              textDayHeaderFontSize: 16,
            }}

            monthTextColor={'red'}
            renderHeader={(date) => {
              // const monthName = moment(date.dateString).format('iYYYY iMMMM iDD');
              return (
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: COLORS.green, fontSize: 25 }}>{hijriDate}</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
```

I tried other possible ways like converting the date for each day and then tried showing it below the gregorian date getting undefined.

I need an help to show both hijri and gregorian dates.

I asked chatGpt but to no use.